# Acerca de la propiedad FreeSpace

Tags: vba

En la instrucción espacio = d.freespace/1024/1024/1024, ¿Qué significa freespace/1024/1024/1024? ¿Qué se indica con el número 1024 repetido 3 veces?

Comment: Tu pregunta es poco descriptiva y es probable que la cierren, te recomiendo que leas [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que puedas elaborar una pregunta que pueda ser respondida por la comunidad.

Answer (score 1):

La propiedad Freespace devuelve el espacio disponible en la unidad.

[FreeSpace (propiedad)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/freespace-property)

Lo devuelve en bytes. Se divide una primera vez entre 1024 para pasarlo a Kbytes.

Se divide una segunda vez entre 1024 para pasarlo de Kbytes a Megabytes.

Y una tercera vez para pasarlo de Megabytes a Gigabytes.

En resumen, lo que hace `espacio = d.freespace/1024/1024/1024, ¿Qué significa freespace/1024/1024/1024` es calcular el espacio libre en la unidad, en Gigabytes.

Comment: Muchas gracias Elier. Saludos.